# ROS-I trajectory downloading using TYPE 11 instead of 12?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to use the trajectory downloading method in order to send trajectory commands to my robot controller. As written below, the trajectory downloading method should use the Joint trajectory message (JOINT_TRAJ):

```
JOINT_TRAJ_PT = 11,  //Joint trajectory point message (typically for streaming)
JOINT_TRAJ = 12,      //Joint trajectory message (typically for trajectory downloading)
```

However, the **JointTrajectoryDownloader** class used in the **generic_joint_downloader_node.cpp**, has a method **send_to_robot** which converts each Joint trajectory point from the Joint trajectory array into a simple message and sends it (with type JOINT_TRAJ_PT = 11)

A piece of code from the **send_to_robot** method:

```
for (int i = 0; i < (int)points.size(); ++i)
  {
    ROS_DEBUG("Sending joints trajectory point[%d]", i);

    points[i].toTopic(msg);
    bool ptRslt = this->connection_->sendMsg(msg);
    if (ptRslt)
      ROS_DEBUG("Point[%d] sent to controller", i);
    else
      ROS_WARN("Failed sent joint point, skipping point");

    rslt &= ptRslt;
  }
```

So I don't understand how should I create a message handler for the JOINT_TRAJ type if what the server gets is only JOINT_TRAJ_PT messages.

An othere matter, this **send_to_robot** method adds a **sequence** to the first and last JOINT_TRAJ_PT messages so it would be possible to know where the path starts and where it ends:

```
 // The first and last points are assigned special sequence values
  points.begin()->setSequence(SpecialSeqValues::START_TRAJECTORY_DOWNLOAD);
  points.back().setSequence(SpecialSeqValues::END_TRAJECTORY);
```

But I don't understand how could my massage handler know how to read this sequence from the sent ByteArray. this sequence is not included in one of the typical simple message types, so how could I know if the integer I'm bytes I'm reading are sequence or joint data?

I desperately need help here, thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/276900/ros-i-trajectory-downloading-using-type-11-instead-of-12?/) by [ManMan88](https://answers.ros.org/users/28824/manman88/) on ROS Answers with karma: 44 on 2017-11-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-29**:\

> As written below, the trajectory downloading method should use the Joint trajectory message (JOINT_TRAJ)

you may feel this is nitpicking, but there is no obligation here. Note the word *typically*, which expresses a possibility that is probably true, but doesn't have to be.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-29**:
As to the rest: in order to avoid a possible [xy-problem](http://xyproblem.info/), could you please tell us what you are actually trying to achieve?

**Comment by [ManMan88](https://answers.ros.org/users/28824/manman88/) on 2017-11-30**:
I'm trying to create a driver (as ROS-I defines it) for a robot.
I have a RT motion controller and I want it to communicate with ROS over TCP with simple messages.
I want the communication to be "trajectory downloading" for the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

O.K I was able to create a Joint trajectory point handler and it works fine (and reads the sequence number fine).
As written here: http://wiki.ros.org/simple_message#Joint_Trajectory_Point_Message , there is a sequence number, so it was my mistake, sorry.

If someone gets stuck on it, this should be the start of the Joint trajectory point handler internalCB method

```
bool JointTrajPtHandler::internalCB(industrial::simple_message::SimpleMessage & in)
{
  bool rtn = false;
  JointTrajPtMessage joint_traj_point_msg;

  if (joint_traj_point_msg.init(in))
  {
     .....
  }
  ....
}
```

---

Originally posted by [ManMan88](https://answers.ros.org/users/28824/manman88/) with karma: 44 on 2017-11-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-30**:\

> so it was my mistake, sorry

well, this isn't too well documented, so don't feel bad.

I've done this a few times (implementing a driver), so perhaps I can assist you. If you'd like, contact me off-list and I can perhaps point you to a few resources.

**Comment by [ManMan88](https://answers.ros.org/users/28824/manman88/) on 2017-11-30**:
Thanks a lot for your help! I would happily contact you if I knew how..?
I also encountered the same question as [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/245978/industrial-robot-client-best-practice-for-implementing-joint_traj_pt_full-msg/) which you have previously answered. how can I contact you?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-12-01**:
you can find my email address in any commit on my github account.